# error importing my CSV data to neo4j Java heap space

Tags: java, import, neo4j, heap-memory

I am getting "Java Heap Space" error when importing csv data in neo4j database.

I have configured following configuration in neo4j.conf.

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=8g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=4g
```

which discribed at

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#_configuring_heap_size_and_garbage_collection

but that not resolve the issue.

following is my screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNuK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at using [`PERIODIC COMMIT`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) when loading, or by using the import tool.